# margin при адаптивной верстке

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

Не могу понять одну простую вещь,- в каких единицах нужно задавать размеры отступов(`margin` и `padding`) при адаптивной верстке.
 Везде вижу разные вещи: одни задают в `px` другие в `%` или `rem`. Как понять, что правильно и как нужно делать?

Comment: В разных ситуациях по разному, я предпочитаю `em` или `%`, они более "пластичные".

Comment: Вам надо попробовать самому, все эти единицы, это придет с практикой. Каждый делает как ему удобно, или как заведено в проекте.

Comment: Насчет вариантов с `em` / `rem`[посмотрите тут.](https://habrahabr.ru/post/280125/)

Comment: В каких единицах вам нужно, в таких и задавйте.

Answer (score 2):

Правильный выбор единицы измерения всегда зависит от ситуации.

### Центирование блока, относительно родителя

Возьмём, к примеру, мой самый частый случай, когда надо центрировать блок:

- `margin: 0 auto` - Центирование по горизонтали
- `margin: auto 0` - Центирование по вертикали
- `margin: auto` - Центрирование по обеим осям

Но всё-таки очень будет жирнейший плюс, если изучите `grid` и `flex` в CSS. Очень незаменимые вещи, так как очень сильно облегчают работу при создании резиновой вёрстки.

Вернёмся к единицам измерения. Выбирайте такие, какие на ваш взгляд будут полезны: чаще всего специалисты имеют свой индивидуальный подход к какой-либо ситуации. Их обозначения очень просты:

- `px` - Пиксели
- `%` - Процент
- `vw` - Процент от ширины страницы
- `vh` - Процент от высоты страницы
- `em` - Процент, относительно родительского класса
- `rem` - Процент, относительно элемента `body`
- `fit-content` - Минимальный вмещаемый размер
- `max-content` - Максимальный вмещаемый размер

Кстати, не стоит забывать про ещё одну полезную плюшку суперсилы резиновой вёрстки.

### Расположение иконки текстового поля справа с отступом

[image: Пример поля с иконкой]

Взгляните сюда. Вы видите иконку, распологающуюся на текстовом поле (которое растянуто на всю ширину блока). Я в такой ситуации задаю эту иконку через `background-image: url(<путь к иконке>)`, а затем запрещаю повтор через `background-repeat: no-repeat`, а теперь самое интересное: нужно правильно задать позицию иконки. По вертикали мы должны расположить по центру, это ясно, но как это правильно сделать по горизонтали? Всё я это веду к полезной функции под названием `calc()`. При помощи её мы прижимаем иконку вправо, но отступаем от правого края `10px`. Выходит такое свойство:

`background-position: 50% calc(100% - 10px)`

Теперь сколько бы мы не сужали окно, иконка всегда будет распологаться справа с отступом.

---

Возможно моё объяснение выглядит немного сырым и недоделанным, но если вы хорошо изучите их свойства и используете на реальной практике, вы получите оточенные и железные навыки резиновой вёрстки. Если здесь есть профессионалы, которые видят в этом ответе ошибку, буду рад, если укажут что именно здесь не так.

А так желаю вам удачи = )

---

Понятия о Flexbox: https://tproger.ru/translations/how-css-flexbox-works/

Понятия о Grid: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Grid_Layout

Answer (score 0):

1vw и 1vh - самый удобный вариант. vw - 1% ширины окна, vh - высоты окна. С помощью них подгоняем элемент на нужное место, на других экранах элемент сам встанет на нужное место.

Comment: А как быть в ситуации, когда нужен отступ от ширины родителя, или блок с фиксированным соотношением сторон?

Answer (score 0):

Нет разницы, адаптивная верстка или нет, всегда ориентируйтесь в целом по проекту, и используйте одну единицу размера, если взяли за основу px, то не переходите на проценты и т.д.
Иногда нужно использовать pt вместо px, например, если Вы отправляете сообщение на почту, так как почтовые программы лучше работают с pt, а значит верстка не поедет.